# How to display table data by today's date?

Tags: php, date

I have a database called gameschedules and a table called dec1212. Inside of this table are the columns `date (YYYY-MM-DD)`, `division`, `field`, `time`, `team1`, and `team2` in that order.

I already have the data displaying on my page but I need to restrict it to only showing rows in my database that have a date that is equal to the current date. So if there are 10 rows and only 5 of them have today's date in the date column, only those should show. Here is my current query code and I know it is wrong but if someone can help me correct it that would be great:

Current code:

```
//specifies that it is getting data from the table and limited num rows
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dec1212` LIMIT 0, 10 ") or die(mysql_error());
```

This is what I tried to do to restrict data by date:

```
//set variable to current date with same format as date column
$myDate = date('Y-m-d');
//pull only rows that match the current date
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dec1212' WHERE date = $myDate()") or die(mysql_error());
```

I know that my code is incorrect so this is why I am asking for help.

Comment: check your data base the value of date col is string format and only have date,if you use datetime data type this method can be not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dec1212` WHERE `date` = CURDATE()") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this just a signal line query

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dec1212 WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(date,"+00:00","-8.00")) = DATE(CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),"+00:00","-8.00"))') or die(mysql_error());**
```

Comment: I received the following error    Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'CONVERT_TZ'

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the time zone, please add which time zone you need, this psd time "-8.00"

Comment: Then use -6:00 for time zone

Answer (score 2):

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d');
//pull only rows that match the current date
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dec1212` WHERE date = '$myDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
//set variable to current date with same format as date column
$myDate = date('Y-m-d');
//pull only rows that match the current date
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dec1212' WHERE date = $myDate") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using variable not the function so just change like this

```
$myDate = date('Y-m-d');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dec1212' WHERE date = '$myDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your date field in database containing the only date, not time

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dec1212' 
            WHERE `date`= '$myDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

if your date field containing datetime datatype then use:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'dec1212' 
            WHERE `date`= date('$myDate')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the database do the work,

```
SELECT * FROM `dec1212` WHERE DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `$myDate` is a variable, not a function. Thus, your code would be :

```
  //set variable to current date with same format as date column
  $myDate = date('Y-m-d');
  //pull only rows that match the current date
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `dec1212` WHERE date = '$myDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Table name or field name should be wrapped with carat `, not single quote `'` or you may omit it.

If you want to use MySQL `NOW()`, you need to consider time zone conversion as Raj Mohan mentioned.